# Best Practices for Overlapping Object/Data Entity Types

Tags: oop, orm, entity, data-modeling, database-normalization

Occasionally I run into situations where all of the conditions below are true for two highly similar, but not quite identical entities or objects. This makes it difficult for me to decide how to model them, either on the database end or in terms of object modeling. I'm going to try to spell out the issue and my questions in detail, because I've found it to be a really difficult modeling problem to define. I'm trying to do both data and object modeling with these entities, so I'm going to use the terminology of both disciplines a little loosely.

1) Both entities share many identical properties, but have a few unique ones not found in the other.

2) One is not a supertype or subtype of another.

3) The overlap is not due to object inheritance.

4) The objects are used for different purposes in the same domain, but often in close proximity in any workflow. This frequently leads those with even moderate domain knowledge to confuse the entities. On the other hand, this fine separation in purposes leads to greater differences between the methods of the associated objects than their properties.

5) In some situations it may be possible to create bridge tables on the database side to express M2M relationships between the entities. Nevertheless, they have so many properties (or columns, on the database side) in common that it might make sense to store them in the same table.

Some cases in point I've run into include:
1) "Product vs. Project confusion" - especially in software marketing, where Products and Projects share many of the same properties. Normally a product will have multiple projects associated with it, but it is also unusual yet conceivable for a project to be used in multiple products.

2) The subtle differences between Features and Components in software development. A feature is developer-centric a means of supplying a benefit, from the customer's point of view, while a component is a means of implementing features on the developer's side. This is a really subtle distinction which nevertheless counts for a lot. For further discussion see Rod Maupin's post at http://www.installationdeveloper.com/347/features-and-components-101/

3) Templates vs. Types in a lot of different problem domains. For example, when identifying types of guitars through a TypeID column, the TypeTable it refers to would probably have columns corresponding to colors, string sizes, body shapes, etc. A template, on the other hand, is something you'd build a guitar from, so it would have different methods than a Type, perhaps linked to an "Apply Template" or "Make Item from Template" menu command. Nevertheless, it would have many of the same columns or properties as a Type, such as color, shape, string size etc. This distinction raises its head in thousands of different object types and templates in many problem domains, not just this narrow example. To complicate matters further, in some situations it might be helpful to associate multiple Templates with a particular Type, and/or vice-versa.

I haven't run into this problem of overlapping entities often, but when it does occur, it becomes a real bottleneck and leads to a lot of waste time refactoring the data and object models. I've read books on both topics and done a lot searches of data/object modeling webpages about the issue, but have yet to see it discussed. The only hits for "overlap" and "data model" I could find on StackOverflow were for differentiating between similar columns in one table or entity, not across tables or entities. My questions are:

1) Is there is a formal name for this issue?

2) Is there a simple shortcut or trick of the trade to identify such overlapping entities at the beginning of the modeling process, rather than much further down the line, when late recognition makes refactoring an issue?

3) How should such overlapping entities be handled? I assume that in terms of OOP, they ought to have separate objects since their methods tend to be different. Inheriting one from the other would be awkward though. A more difficult question would be whether or not it would make sense to use separate tables on the database end. Combining them might require a complex series of views plus waste storage space when the properties/columns they don't have in common are left null. Storing them in separate tables might also be wasteful though, if the common properties could be stored in single columns.

It's a tricky issue to even recognize, let alone handle. I have only a moderate amount of experience with data/object modeling, so the input of someone who really knows what they're doing would be helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: Another example of an overlap is data modeling vs software engineering.  I prefer to use OOP for systems modeling and the relational model for domain modeling, keeping the disciplines orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question concerns both database modeling aspects that object-oriented (programming) modeling aspects. Let’s start from an abstract point of view.

You say:

> 1) Both entities share many identical properties, but have a few unique ones not found in the other.
>
> 2) One is not a supertype or subtype of another.

and:

> 3) The overlap is not due to object inheritance.

But note that *inheritance* should not to be confused with *subtyping*, even if many times they are tied together!  See for instance [Inheritance (object-oriented programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) in Wikipedia, where this statement is supported by two citations [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)#cite_note-2),[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)#cite_note-3)].

In other words, even if A is not a subtype of B, and B is not a subtype of A, you can find a C from which both A and B inherits attributes.

So, you can think or not of this C as an “abstract supertype” of both A and B; but in any case it is convenient consider it as common ancestor, at least from a database point of view, so that factorize the common attributes in a “supertable”.

Then, from the object-oriented programming side, you can see A or B as subtype of C or simple as two different things, depending on the characteristics of your Object-Relational Mapping tools, from the problem at hand, etc.

Of course, this way of modelling things does not prohibit that A and B, in addition to inherit from C, have one or more relations between them, as in the example Products-Projects that you have done.

So, here is my answer to your four final questions:

1) Yes, it is called inheritance.

2) You can check if two entities have a significant number of common attributes.

3) You can model them in the database with a common table, that perhaps has some common property like integrity constraints, and with two tables that have a foreign key to it. Of course this rule is not to be applied blindly, but can have exception as all the human rules. From the programming point of view, on the other hand, you can decide to model them both with a supertype or not. This dependes on many factors, and should be decided on a case by case basis.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, which I have 2 further questions about. One of the reasons I haven't used inheritance is that in the examples I've seen, neither entity is clearly dominant. If I use a supertype, could I inherit both from that? I also did not use supertypes because there is no real-world object that subsumes both templates & types, products & projects, or features & components. Is it wise to create a base table for a dummy supertype and use some generic name for the base table, like TemplateTypeTable, ProductProjectTable or FeatureComponentTable? Thanks! :)

Comment: P.S. I was going to upvote your answer but'll have to wait till I get enough rep points. :)

Comment: 1) Yes, you can inherit both from the same supertype. 2) I think this is reasonable, particularly if you have a number of attributes in common. Sometimes I found that, after defining a common supertype, I find also some useful operation on them.  P.S. Even if you cannot upvote, you could accept the answer by clicking on the mark, but do this *only* if you are satisfied with the answer :)

Comment: Done :) I think only one minor point in my question is left unanswered: is there a formal/informal name for this overlapping entity problem in either data or object modeling lingo? This part's not that big a deal, it's just a convenience.

Comment: Thanks. As I said, you can call it inheritance, since this is what happen: a type inherits properties from another (even if it is *not* a subtype).

Comment: Cool. That'll work. I just didn't know if there was some specific term, like "multiple overlapping inheritance" or whatever, just in case I encountered it in the modeling literature somewhere. Thanks for your help, this'll really help me cut through some development bottlenecks :)